# error: Binary XML file line#3: You must supply a layout width attribute

Tags: android, runtime-error

i'va already read all answers related with these questions and I'm sure none solves my problem, I'm getting crazy with this error, please any help would be appreciated

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_scaned_value"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/scanedFormat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title_scaned_value_empty"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/scanedValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title_scaned_value_empty"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/title_scan"
    android:onClick="commandScan"/>
 <Button 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="productes"
    android:onClick="productes"/>
```

My activity related with this layout works fine, but when i click a button to start another activity this error appears.
I'm workin with Zxing library and here's my CaptureActivity:

```
package org.example.sherlock_;

import org.example.sherlock_.helpers.ExceptionHelper;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.client.android.result.ResultHandler;

public class CaptureActivity extends com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity {

@Override
public void handleDecodeInternally(Result rawResult, ResultHandler resultHandler, Bitmap barcode) {
    //super.handleDecodeInternally(rawResult, resultHandler, barcode);

    try {

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra(com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
        resultIntent.putExtra(com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Scan.RESULT, resultHandler.getDisplayContents());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExceptionHelper.manage(this, e);
    }
}
```

}

I post my MainActivity too because I'm going really mad :)

```
package org.example.sherlock_;




import org.example.sherlock_.helpers.ExceptionHelper;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;


 public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {


private TextView scanedValue;
private TextView scanedFormat;
private final static int SCAN_CODE_REQUEST_CODE = 123456;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scanedValue  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanedValue);
    scanedFormat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scanedFormat);

    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int pRequestCode, int pResultCode, Intent pData) {
    try {

        if (pRequestCode == SCAN_CODE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (pResultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String result = pData.getStringExtra

(com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Scan.RESULT);
                String format = pData.getStringExtra

(com.google.zxing.client.android.Intents.Scan.RESULT_FORMAT);



                if (scanedValue != null) {
                    if (result != null && 
!result.trim().equals("")) {
                        scanedValue.setText(result);
                        //if(db != null){


                            //String valor= result  ;
                        //}

                    } else {


scanedValue.setText(getString(R.string.title_scaned_value_empty));
                    }
                }

                if (scanedFormat != null) {
                    if (format != null &&  
!format.trim().equals("")) {
                        scanedFormat.setText(format);
                        //if(db != null){
                        //String tipus = format;
                        //}
                    } else {

scanedFormat.setText(getString(R.string.title_scaned_value_empty));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (scanedValue != null)

scanedValue.setText(getString(R.string.title_scaned_value_empty));
                if (scanedFormat != null)

scanedFormat.setText(getString(R.string.title_scaned_value_empty));
            }
        }

        //Insertamos los datos en la tabla Usuarios
       // db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Productes (codi, tipus, valor) " +
              //     "VALUES (" + i + ", '" + tipus +"', '"+ valor +"')");

       // db.close();
        //i+=i;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExceptionHelper.manage(this, e);
    }

}

public void commandScan(View pView) {
    try {

        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
        captureIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(captureIntent, SCAN_CODE_REQUEST_CODE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        ExceptionHelper.manage(this, e);
    }
}








@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "configuración pulsado"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 

    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Post the layout code for the second Activity.

Comment: "My activity related with this layout works fine, but when i click a button to start another activity this error appears." That right there tells you that you need to post the layout for the *other* activity :)

Comment: Can you verify if you forgot to put the methods commandScan and/or productes public!